# How to get a mean value for several entries in the attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis-processing, spatial-statistics

I have the following attribute table showing Drought Index values ("VHI_Index") and names of country districts ("NAME_3") in Ethiopia. There are multiple VHI values for every district and I want to build a new (virtual) table with a column of the district names and a second column with the mean VHI values for every district. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

```
select avg(vhi_index) as total,  id_3, name_3 from data1 
group by id_3
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Worked out well, thanks!